# RSpec tests for custom username routes are failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rspec, custom-routes

I have a constrained route that matches usernames like this:

```
controller :users, :path => '/:username', :as => :user, :constrain => { :username => /^_?[a-z]_?(?:[a-z0-9]_?)*$/i } do
   # lots of nested routes go here
end
```

When I go to write RSpec tests for this (versus using `user_id` like normal), all the tests are failing because it "can't find the route" even though it works fine on the server.

```
describe "for an invalid request" do
  it "should render a 404 if an associated photo is not found" do
    # give it a bad photo id
    xhr :post, :destroy, :id => "999999", :photo_id => "999999", :username => @photo_owner.username
    # not found
    response.status.should == not_found
  end
end
```

This test was working fine when I was using the `user_id` in my routes prior to switching to usernames:

```
resources :users do
  # nested routes
end
```

and

```
xhr :post, :destroy, :id => "999999", :photo_id => "999999", :user_id => @photo_owner.id
```

So what am I doing wrong and what has changed?

My server console shows this which means I should have all of the parameters passed in properly:

```
Processing by TagsController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"constrain"=>{"username"=>/^_?[a-z]_?(?:[a-z0-9]_?)*$/i}, "username"=>"rubynewb", "photo_id"=>"2004-the-title-of-the-photo-here", "id"=>"1797"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:constraints => {...}` in your route definition.

You have one too many parameters being passed...

```
"constrain"=>{"username"=>/^_?[a-z]_?(?:[a-z0-9]_?)*$/i}
```

Rails doesn't recognize `:constrain`, therefore it and it's contents are passed along as a parameter instead of being processed by the Rails router.